# How to start a non-validating peer in Hyperledger?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, peer

A validating peer can be started in Hyperledger using the following command:

```
docker run --rm -it -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375 -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp1 -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true -e CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE=172.17.0.2:7051 hyperledger/fabric-peer peer node start
```

What is the command to start a non-validating peer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of `core.yaml` file. If you carefully read `core.yaml` file you will see the following lines,

> # Validator defines whether this peer is a validating peer or not,
>   and if
>       # it is enabled, what consensus plugin to load
>       validator:
>           enabled: true

Or you could implement membership services and create a peer with `Non-validator` privilege level.

This is what it says in `membersrvc.yaml` file,

> Default users to be registered with the CA on first launch.  The role is a binary OR
>    of the different roles a user can have:
>
> - simple client such as a wallet: CLIENT
> - non-validating peer: PEER
> - validating client: VALIDATOR
> - auditing client: AUDITOR

and the levels,

> The fields of each user are as follows:
>    1:client, 2: peer, 4: validator, 8: auditor

The following users are also available to register as non-validating peer in the same file,

```
 test_nvp0: 2 iywrPBDEPl0K bank_a
 test_nvp1: 2 DcYXuRSocuqd institution_a
 test_nvp2: 2 flpChShlY7xt bank_c
 test_nvp3: 2 jeruawMomclo bank_a
 test_nvp4: 2 RMYVxSZCk370 institution_a
 test_nvp5: 2 XHYVCIJGZGK7 bank_b
 test_nvp6: 2 4cIn63j8ahYp bank_a
 test_nvp7: 2 E7FAJUtWVn2h institution_a
 test_nvp8: 2 LJu8DkUilBEH bank_a
 test_nvp9: 2 VlEsBsiyXSjw institution_a
```

You can also look at the [asset management example app](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/chaincode/go/asset_management/app) which bootstraps a non-validating peer and constructs fabric confidential transactions to deploy, invoke and query the chaincode.

Comment: Thank you @sufiyan-ghori.  I will update the .yaml file and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

using docker-compose to up peer
using environment to override core.yaml
-CORE_PEER_VALIDATOR_ENABLED = false

please do not only use docker run, docker-compose can set environments easily.

Comment: Thanks @king3000.  Is there a document providing a list of environment variables that can be used to override the settings of core.yaml.  I tried to search the Internet but only found discussion on particular variables but a comprehensive list (including their description) cannot be found.